# Using Ajax to show data in combobox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to show the data from my database in my combobox with ajax but then I run the script my combobox stays empty.

Here is my combobox

```
<select id="name" name="name">
    <option value= ""></option>
</select>
```

With the following PHP script I am trying to select the data from my database:

```
<?php    
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) ;
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error) ;
}else {

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM scu_stock';    
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) ;
  if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
     $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
    echo $result['name'];
  }else{
     $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
    echo "error";
  }    
} 
?>
```

The following code should enter the data in the combobox:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
  function getCode() { 
    console.log("getCode before ajax", jQuery('#name').val());
    jQuery.ajax({ 
      url: './get/get1.php', 
      method: 'POST', 
      data: {'id' : jQuery('#name').val()},
      success: function(response){ 
        console.log("getCode after ajax", jQuery('#name').val());
        jQuery('#name').val(response);
      }, 
      error: function (request, status, error) { 
        alert(request.responseText); 
      }, 
    });                 
  } 
</script>
```

The script returns empty and I cant see any changes in the combobox. Does someone know what is wrong with the script?

**Update 1:**

When I change the combobox to a textbox I can see that the textbox is filled with data. I cant get the data that is returned from the database in the combobox. Does someone know a solution for this problem?

This works:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
```

This is not working:

```
<select id="name" name="name">
    <option value= ""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: The response I get is empty. There is nothing wrong with the request. I included the jquery library in the project as you can see above. There are no errors reported and I am using this on a web server

Comment: `data: {'id' : jQuery('#name').val()},` will have no value until an option is selected. You're not sending anything to the PHP. Where do you call `getCode()`?

Comment: I call the getCode() with a onChange event in another textbox: `<input type="text" name="id" id="id" onChange='getCode(this.value)'>`. I dont think there is something wrong with this part of the code. In the console I can see that Ajax script is running. But the result is empty

Comment: Well, there is not much we can do if there are no errors and you say the request is working fine. There *has* to be something wrong.

Comment: See `update 1` in my first post

Comment: Can you show us what is returned? You probably need to fetch all then JSON encode.

Comment: I only get the first row from the database. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/CSP7mAd

Answer (score 1):

In your case the response should be a JSON Array in bellow mentioned format.

```
 var response = [{"option": "option1", "value" : "option1"];
```

And you need to select the default selected option based on some condition of your choice such as if the option value matches some specific string.

To render the select options, you can change the code in the following way.

```
 function getCode() { 
   console.log("getCode before ajax", jQuery('#name').val());
   jQuery.ajax({ 
      url: './get/get1.php', 
      method: 'POST', 
      data: {'id' : jQuery('#name').val()},
      success: function(response){ 
         console.log("getCode after ajax", jQuery('#name').val());
         //jQuery('#name').val(response); // change this line based on your default selected line condition
         $.each(response, function(index,json){
             jQuery('#name')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr({"value": response, "selected":"selected"}).text(response));
            });
      }, 
      error: function (request, status, error) { 
         alert(request.responseText); 
      }, 
   });                 
 }
```

You can also get rid of bellow line as it will be populated through your JSON Response, you don't need to add a blank option.

```
<option value= ""></option>
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didnt solve my problem. In the console I can see a response, but I dont see the data in the combobox.

Comment: I think if you are returning only one value in response, which is suitable for text Input not for a select element. But even if you want to use Select element, make sure you are make the option selected when you are populating the data.
Best if you can share me your response that would helpful for me to change the above code accordingly.

Comment: Changed the code, please check if it solves your problem or not

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change your PHP to return all of the rows:

```
 if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
     $result = json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($res)) ; // fetch all and json_encode()
  }else{
    $result = json_encode(array('error' => 'no rows returned'));
 }
 echo $result;
```

Then you need to loop through the returned results in the AJAX to populate the drop-down:

```
success: function(response){ 
    console.log("getCode after ajax", jQuery('#name').val());
       $.each(response, function(index,json){
           jQuery('#name')
               .append($("<option></option>")
               .attr("value",response.value).text(response.value));
           });
       },
```

`response.value` will need to be tweaked to match what you return in the JSON. We'd need to see the JSON to tell you what exactly to put here.

Comment: Did you try this John?